# Feed dialog generating errors with iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, dialog, publish, facebook-feed

**UPDATE: This problem was resolved when facebook fixed their service.**

I'm trying to get the feed dialog to work for sharing with facebook. I had it all working before with the old, deprecated API and SDK, but have just moved to using the current iPhone SDK and am trying an example [directly from the documenation here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/);

I keep getting the error, "Error with publishing" "There was a problem generating the Feed story from the provided data" and I cannot see what I'm doing wrong. Note that I have taken out the message parameter as it was deprecated in July, but I get the same problem whether or not that parameter is present.

```
Facebook *facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kFacebookAppId andDelegate:self];


NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               kFacebookAppId, @"app_id",
                               @"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/", @"link",
                               @"http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg", @"picture",
                               @"Facebook Dialogs", @"name",
                               @"Reference Documentation", @"caption",
                               @"Using Dialogs to interact with users.", @"description",
                               nil];   

[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong?
Thanks!

[image: Here's the error screen]

Comment: @answerers: "me too" is not an answer. Upvote and comment unless you have a solution.

Comment: Maybe posting on http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/ can have more effect : http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7585400/ios-publishing-on-feed-no-more-functionnal

Comment: Pretty sure that's where I posted it ... but it seems that it appears on the main SO site as well.

Comment: As an update, Facebook have assigned this as a high priority bug according to feedback on the developer bug report that was posted earlier. I'm unclear as to why this post has now been deleted, but if you are a facebook developer you can track the status on bug 295765603772094.

Comment: @kenji - facebook.stackoverflow.com is just a view of 'facebook' tagged questions on stackoverflow - i'm already accessing this Q there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you are doing something wrong.

Just experienced the same problem with with my working app.

Most likely an issue on the side of facebook

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation - such a pain when this happens at the point of trying to develop something!

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue on my Android application. I guess they have deprecated some APIs, cannot say for sure though.

Comment: Same issue here, haven't gotten this before.

Answer (score 7):

The page http://developers.facebook.com/live_status reports the issue today at 16:49 (GMT+1)

To follow the issue : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/295765603772094

Comment: Facebook now reporting that the issue is resolved. Seems to work for me now.

Comment: It now works for Android too. Would you mind checking if the cancel button works fine though ? Mine just refreshes the publish dialog, does not take it back to my app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use direct REST API or Graph API calls that are working now.